# What does body.GetPosition,body.GetWorldCenter stand for in Box2D?

Tags: actionscript, box2d

Recently I have a new project that uses Box2D as physics engine. And I am having some trouble with the body's position.

I want to draw images on the sprite, so I just use `body.GetPosition` as image's position. But I found that `body.GetPosition` returns the same value as `body.GetWorldCenter`, and I just wondering that I did something wrong.

I use `box2d flash 2.1a` in my project. And I currently subtract this position with half-width and half-height to walk around. Also, can you tell me if there is some way to solve my problem or draw the image in the correct positon in Box2D.

Thank you.

## update

so sorry to post before read manual.
after RTM I got that body has two points,first is **origin point** and the second is **center of mass** ,so a regular shape's world center is always the same as it's origin point. sorry to post is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the image in the userdata for the body? Your getting the body's position but you need to have a function that runs each world tick that can set the images position to the new location. Box2d is just numbers defining a simulation. Those numbers are constantly updating so the image needs to have position set each time there is a game tick. Hope this helps

Comment: No problem :) if I helped you out please consider pressing the green tick to mark the answer as correct ;)